# Downloading fonts is not supported in dockerized puppetter

Tags: node.js, docker, fonts, puppeteer

I am trying to take screenshot of my website inside puppetter, but the font is not printed properly, I am using a custom font. I am not sure if this line of code is not executing inside puppetter!

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have tried to wait until document's font is ready, but still not working, the font still not applied

```
await page.evaluateHandle('document.fonts.ready');
```

I am using puppeteer built-in chromium browser.
Also 
I am using docker-compose, and I am giving `sys_admin` to `cap_add`attribute to this service .

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.7.0-alpine AS base
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser" \
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    ttf-freefont \
    chromium \
     && npm install puppeteer@1.10.0

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["npm"]
CMD ["start"]
```

This is how it looks like inside docker

[image]

That is how the font in chrome

[image]

Comment: What does the font looks like on the screenshot?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher, I add the screenshot and the Dockerfile as well

Comment: What does the font look like on your normal chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I post an issue on [puppetter github account](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4996), and they said, it's probably chromium doesn't provide full support for all Arabic font, and they suggest to install chrome inside the container.

```
FROM node:10-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
&& sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
  --no-install-recommends \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```